# What's the right choice to run a cooler Cpu (quiter laptop)?

Tags: laptop, cpu, cpu-usage, clockspeed, cpu-temperature

Assuming that on the same laptop with an intel "i-series" processor I could have exactly the same workload, in order to achieve the lowest cpu temperatures it would be better:

- Higher CPU clock speed, with a low % of usage.
- Lower  CPU clock speed, with a high % of usage.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are way too many factors in how much heat is produced. It's way more than clock speed + percentage of utilization. If thermodynamics was that straight forward, we'd all be masters of it.

Comment: Well, one thing is certain;  
high utilization% is going to generate heat and by that; fan noise.

Answer (score 0):

As I have understeanded, you are trying to find the lowest CPU temperature, which results in a quieter cooling fan. In my opinion, I don't think that it's possible to make the fan quieter (to lower the temperature) without having both lower CPU frequency and lower CPU usage.

But you can make the fan quieter if you have a power saving/silent mode option embedded in your BIOS (which may reduce the CPU fan rpm).

To keep it cool, try not to run intensive apps in the background.

Check to see if you have such an option or something similar in your BIOS settings.

Comment: I'll try to be more specific: i can set my cpu either with higher or lower clock.
with the same workload, with higher clock I get 20-30% of cpu-usage but with the lower clock I get 60-80% of cpu-usage (assuming the same workload) so I was trying to understand which scenario would give me the lowest temperature or if it was the same afterall because the temperature is a result of both of them

Comment: if you are curious, you can use a program like Realtemp to log your CPU temperature in a text file as you modify your CPU clock. For e.g,  if you have low clock and high usage, log the temperature. If you have high clock and low usage, log the temperature. But i don't think that can make a huge difference between temperatures. It's up to you what you do.